# D3.js: circle color change on title mouseover doesn't work

Tags: d3.js, hover, mouseover, geometry, onmouseover

I'm appending some text to D3.js circles and want the circles to change color mouseover, also on mouseover on the text.

Currently the circles do change color on mouseover, but when hovering over the text, the circle mouseover doesn't work anymore (logical: I'm hovering over the text). How do I get the circles to also change color when hovering over the text?

My code (gnode is a earlier defined circle):

```
var label = gnode.append("text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.key ; })
    .attr("font-size", function(d) {return 12 + d.value[0]/4})
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .call(force.drag)
    .on("mouseover", function(d){
        this.style.cursor='pointer';
        d3.select( "#" + d.key.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_'))
            .attr("id", "none")
            .classed("mouse_over",true)
            .classed("mouse_out",false);
```

thanks

Comment: Have you written css for class mouse_over and mouse_out.And if possible prepare jsfiddle of it

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply putting all the elements belonging together inside a group. Then attach the mouse events to the group instead of the elements themselves.

First create svg element and append data:

```
var svg = d3.select("#main")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("id", "svgElement")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var svgg = svg.selectAll("g.myGroup")
    .data(myData)
    .enter()
    .append("g");
```

Then add your elements via the `each` function:

```
svgg.each(function (d, i) {
    selection = d3.select(this);
    // ... append to this selection
});
```

Now attach mouse events to the group:

```
svgg.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    d3.select(this) // Select and do something
});
```

You can find the working fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/77XLD/1/

Note that the event fires when either moving over the line of the circle and also when hovering over the text.